# How can I add the player to the room that has the most person but not full using Photon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, real-time-multiplayer, photon-controller

How can I add the player to the room that has the most person but not full using Photon, I'm working on a multiplayer game that using photon, I read the Photon's page documents but not seems to have any well detailed Infos, What I want is when the player click play, it took him to a server that has most people in it but not full, so it can make gameplay faster and they don't have to wait for other players, any tutorials about this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `OnRoomListUpdate` function to keep track of the list of rooms

```
List<RoomInfo> RoomsInfo { get; set; }

void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
{
    RoomsInfo = roomList.ToList();
}
```

Now go throug the list to check that the player count is not full:

```
// Select non full rooms
var validRooms = RoomsInfo.Where(x => x.PlayerCount != x.MaxPlayers);

// Select the one of the most players
var room = validRooms.OrderByDescending(x => x.PlayerCount).FirstOrDefault();
```

And that would be the room you want.